# Orchard CMS package a precompiled module

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

Is a way to package a precompiled module that has binaries in the bin folder, and no source files?

I have tried to create a precompiled build of Orchard 1.10.1, which has the module in the modules folder built in the desired state. However when you I ran the orchard command line on the precompiled build, there were no commands available, so I could not execute the package module command.

I am looking to build module packages to push module updates to a precompiled Orchard instance.

Comment: Did you include the `Module.txt` file?

Comment: I don't think you need to package the module. Just push the new dll to the server.